# Splitting Text Across Divs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a game where I need to split a long text into 500 words and divide them into separate divs. I have been working on some code that I pieced to together because my coding is a little weak.  As you can see, the code splits up the text and creates a new div within each div with the class 'column' but I would like for each div with the class 'column' to have its portion of the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/CheesyGreen/mmungy5e/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     
    var contentBlocks = $('#content').text().replace(/.{500}\S*\.\s+/g, '$&@').split(/\.\s+@/);
    var contentBlocksLength = contentBlocks.length;


    var $columns = $('.column'),
        $data = $columns.first().find('p'),
        size = $data.size(),
        columnSize = size / $columns.length;
        


 $('#content').html('');




$.each(contentBlocks, function( index, value ) {
    $('.column').append($('<div class="textBlock">' + value + ((index != contentBlocksLength - 1) ? '.' : '') + '</div>'));
});


});
```

```css
.column {
    border: 5px solid orange;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    border: 5px solid red;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column" id="content">Ricky Thomas Ponting, AO (born 19 December 1974), nicknamed Punter, is an Australian cricketer, and former captain of the Australia national cricket team between 2004 and 2011 in Test cricket and 2002 and 2011 in One Day International cricket. He is a specialist right-handed batsman, slips and close catching fielder, as well as a very occasional bowler. He represents the Tasmanian Tigers in Australian domestic cricket, the Hobart Hurricanes in the Big Bash League, and played in the Indian Premier League with the Kolkata Knight Riders in 2008. He is widely considered by many to be one of the best batsmen of the modern era, along with Sachin Tendulkar of India and Brian Lara of the West Indies. On 1 December 2006, he reached the highest rating achieved by a Test batsman in the last 50 years. Ponting made his first-class debut for Tasmania in November 1992, when just 17 years and 337 days old, becoming the youngest Tasmanian to play in a Sheffield Shield match. However, he had to wait until 1995 before making his One Day International (ODI) debut, during a quadrangular tournament in New Zealand in a match against South Africa. His Test debut followed shortly after, when selected for the first Test of the 1995 home series against Sri Lanka in Perth, in which he scored 96. He lost his place in the national team several times in the period before early-1999, due to lack of form and discipline, before becoming One Day International captain in early-2002 and Test captain in early-2004. After being involved in over 160 Tests and 370 ODIs, Ponting is Australia's leading run-scorer in Test and ODI cricket. He is one of only four players (along with Sachin Tendulkar, Rahul Dravid and Jacques Kallis) in history to have scored 13,000 Test runs. Statistically, he is one of the most successful captains of all time, with 48 victories in 77 Tests between 2004 and 31 December 2010, while as a player he is also the only cricketer in history to be involved in 100 Test victories.[1] On 29 November 2012 Ponting announced his retirement from Test cricket, the day before he would play in the Perth Test against South Africa. This was his 168th and last Test appearance,[2] equalling the Australian record held by Steve Waugh.[3][4] Ricky Ponting retired on 3 December 2012 with a Test batting average of 51.85.[5] He continued to play cricket around the world. In February 2013 it was announced that he would be captaining the Mumbai Indians team in the Indian Premier League.[6] and in March 2013 he was announced as the first international franchise player for the Caribbean Premier League.[7] Later that month it was revealed by Ponting that this would be his last season playing cricket, as at the end of the competition he would be retiring from all forms of the game.[8] In his final first class innings for Surrey against Notts he hit an unbeaten 169 bringing up a total of 82 first class 100s in an illustrious county career.
<p>
Candlestick Park hosted the Giants from 1960 to 1999 and the 49ers from 1971 until 2013.
The San </p>
<p>
testingThe San </p>
</div>

<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
```

Comment: did you use the CSS column property? it's a simpler and quicker way to split the paragraph into columns.  just use                   .column {column: 3 /* or change it according to your own need*/}

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) instead?

```css
.column {
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="column" id="content">Ricky Thomas Ponting, AO (born 19 December 1974), nicknamed Punter, is an Australian cricketer, and former captain of the Australia national cricket team between 2004 and 2011 in Test cricket and 2002 and 2011 in One Day International cricket. He is a
  specialist right-handed batsman, slips and close catching fielder, as well as a very occasional bowler. He represents the Tasmanian Tigers in Australian domestic cricket, the Hobart Hurricanes in the Big Bash League, and played in the Indian Premier
  League with the Kolkata Knight Riders in 2008. He is widely considered by many to be one of the best batsmen of the modern era, along with Sachin Tendulkar of India and Brian Lara of the West Indies. On 1 December 2006, he reached the highest rating
  achieved by a Test batsman in the last 50 years. Ponting made his first-class debut for Tasmania in November 1992, when just 17 years and 337 days old, becoming the youngest Tasmanian to play in a Sheffield Shield match. However, he had to wait until
  1995 before making his One Day International (ODI) debut, during a quadrangular tournament in New Zealand in a match against South Africa. His Test debut followed shortly after, when selected for the first Test of the 1995 home series against Sri Lanka
  in Perth, in which he scored 96. He lost his place in the national team several times in the period before early-1999, due to lack of form and discipline, before becoming One Day International captain in early-2002 and Test captain in early-2004. After
  being involved in over 160 Tests and 370 ODIs, Ponting is Australia's leading run-scorer in Test and ODI cricket. He is one of only four players (along with Sachin Tendulkar, Rahul Dravid and Jacques Kallis) in history to have scored 13,000 Test runs.
  Statistically, he is one of the most successful captains of all time, with 48 victories in 77 Tests between 2004 and 31 December 2010, while as a player he is also the only cricketer in history to be involved in 100 Test victories.[1] On 29 November
  2012 Ponting announced his retirement from Test cricket, the day before he would play in the Perth Test against South Africa. This was his 168th and last Test appearance,[2] equalling the Australian record held by Steve Waugh.[3][4] Ricky Ponting retired
  on 3 December 2012 with a Test batting average of 51.85.[5] He continued to play cricket around the world. In February 2013 it was announced that he would be captaining the Mumbai Indians team in the Indian Premier League.[6] and in March 2013 he was
  announced as the first international franchise player for the Caribbean Premier League.[7] Later that month it was revealed by Ponting that this would be his last season playing cricket, as at the end of the competition he would be retiring from all
  forms of the game.[8] In his final first class innings for Surrey against Notts he hit an unbeaten 169 bringing up a total of 82 first class 100s in an illustrious county career.

</div>
```

Comment: using CSS would be easy to implement but once I put my animation and project together it would not make sense. The divs (or columns) are not spread out across the animation uniformly and may differ depending on the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but see if this update helps any.  This code can (should) be cleaned up a lot, but i'm not sure exactly what you're looking for so this might help you on your way.

https://jsfiddle.net/mmungy5e/15/

```
<div class="hide" id="content">Ricky Thomas Ponting, AO (born 19 December 1974), nicknamed Punter, is an Australian cricketer, and former captain of the Australia national cricket team between 2004 and 2011 in Test cricket and 2002 and 2011 in One Day International cricket. He is a specialist right-handed batsman, slips and close catching fielder, as well as a very occasional bowler. He represents the Tasmanian Tigers in Australian domestic cricket, the Hobart Hurricanes in the Big Bash League, and played in the Indian Premier League with the Kolkata Knight Riders in 2008. He is widely considered by many to be one of the best batsmen of the modern era, along with Sachin Tendulkar of India and Brian Lara of the West Indies. On 1 December 2006, he reached the highest rating achieved by a Test batsman in the last 50 years. Ponting made his first-class debut for Tasmania in November 1992, when just 17 years and 337 days old, becoming the youngest Tasmanian to play in a Sheffield Shield match. However, he had to wait until 1995 before making his One Day International (ODI) debut, during a quadrangular tournament in New Zealand in a match against South Africa. His Test debut followed shortly after, when selected for the first Test of the 1995 home series against Sri Lanka in Perth, in which he scored 96. He lost his place in the national team several times in the period before early-1999, due to lack of form and discipline, before becoming One Day International captain in early-2002 and Test captain in early-2004. After being involved in over 160 Tests and 370 ODIs, Ponting is Australia's leading run-scorer in Test and ODI cricket. He is one of only four players (along with Sachin Tendulkar, Rahul Dravid and Jacques Kallis) in history to have scored 13,000 Test runs. Statistically, he is one of the most successful captains of all time, with 48 victories in 77 Tests between 2004 and 31 December 2010, while as a player he is also the only cricketer in history to be involved in 100 Test victories.[1] On 29 November 2012 Ponting announced his retirement from Test cricket, the day before he would play in the Perth Test against South Africa. This was his 168th and last Test appearance,[2] equalling the Australian record held by Steve Waugh.[3][4] Ricky Ponting retired on 3 December 2012 with a Test batting average of 51.85.[5] He continued to play cricket around the world. In February 2013 it was announced that he would be captaining the Mumbai Indians team in the Indian Premier League.[6] and in March 2013 he was announced as the first international franchise player for the Caribbean Premier League.[7] Later that month it was revealed by Ponting that this would be his last season playing cricket, as at the end of the competition he would be retiring from all forms of the game.[8] In his final first class innings for Surrey against Notts he hit an unbeaten 169 bringing up a total of 82 first class 100s in an illustrious county career.
<p>
Candlestick Park hosted the Giants from 1960 to 1999 and the 49ers from 1971 until 2013.
The San </p>
<p>
testingThe San </p>
</div>

<div class="columns"></div>
```

css

```
.column {
    border: 5px solid orange;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    border: 5px solid red;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var contentBlocks = $('#content').text().replace(/.{500}\S*\.\s+/g, '$&@').split(/\.\s+@/);
    var contentBlocksLength = contentBlocks.length;


    var $columns = $('.column'),
        $data = $columns.first().find('p'),
        size = $data.size(),
        columnSize = size / $columns.length;



    $('#content').html('');




$.each(contentBlocks, function( index, value ) {
    $('.columns').append($('<div class="column textBlock">' + value + ((index != contentBlocksLength - 1) ? '.' : '') + '</div>'));
});


});
```

Comment: Thank you @Dillon. I went back and cleaned up a bit then found a solution. You answer was very close - I ust needed to portion out the tet among multiple divs. http://jsfiddle.net/CheesyGreen/m2t2c81g/

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this solution. enter code here

https://jsfiddle.net/CheesyGreen/m2t2c81g/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     
    var contentBlocks = $('#content').text().replace(/.{500}\S*\.\s+/g, '$&@').split(/\.\s+@/);
    
    var contentBlocksLength = contentBlocks.length;

        
var content = [
    [  '#content', contentBlocks[0] ],
    [  '#content2', contentBlocks[1] ],
    [  '#content3', contentBlocks[2] ],
    [  '#content4', contentBlocks[3] ],
    [  '#content5', contentBlocks[4] ],
    [  '#content6', contentBlocks[5] ],
    [  '#content7', contentBlocks[6] ],
    [  '#content8', contentBlocks[7] ],
    [  '#content9', contentBlocks[8] ],
    
];


$.each(content , function( index, obj ) {
 if(obj[1] === undefined) {$(obj[0]).hide();
} 
else {
 $(obj[0]).html(obj[1]);
}
 
});


//$.each(content , function( index, obj ) {
  //  $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
   // console.log(value[0][0])

 //   });
//});



});
```

```css
.columns {
    border: 5px solid orange;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    border: 5px solid red;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns" id="content">Ricky Thomas Ponting, AO (born 19 December 1974), nicknamed Punter, is an Australian cricketer, and former captain of the Australia national cricket team between 2004 and 2011 in Test cricket and 2002 and 2011 in One Day International cricket. He is a specialist right-handed batsman, slips and close catching fielder, as well as a very occasional bowler. He represents the Tasmanian Tigers in Australian domestic cricket, the Hobart Hurricanes in the Big Bash League, and played in the Indian Premier League with the Kolkata Knight Riders in 2008. He is widely considered by many to be one of the best batsmen of the modern era, along with Sachin Tendulkar of India and Brian Lara of the West Indies. On 1 December 2006, he reached the highest rating achieved by a Test batsman in the last 50 years. Ponting made his first-class debut for Tasmania in November 1992, when just 17 years and 337 days old, becoming the youngest Tasmanian to play in a Sheffield Shield match. However, he had to wait until 1995 before making his One Day International (ODI) debut, during a quadrangular tournament in New Zealand in a match against South Africa. His Test debut followed shortly after, when selected for the first Test of the 1995 home series against Sri Lanka in Perth, in which he scored 96. He lost his place in the national team several times in the period before early-1999, due to lack of form and discipline, before becoming One Day International captain in early-2002 and Test captain in early-2004. After being involved in over 160 Tests and 370 ODIs, Ponting is Australia's leading run-scorer in Test and ODI cricket. He is one of only four players (along with Sachin Tendulkar, Rahul Dravid and Jacques Kallis) in history to have scored 13,000 Test runs. Statistically, he is one of the most successful captains of all time, with 48 victories in 77 Tests between 2004 and 31 December 2010, while as a player he is also the only cricketer in history to be involved in 100 Test victories.[1] On 29 November 2012 Ponting announced his retirement from Test cricket, the day before he would play in the Perth Test against South Africa. This was his 168th and last Test appearance,[2] equalling the Australian record held by Steve Waugh.[3][4] Ricky Ponting retired on 3 December 2012 with a Test batting average of 51.85.[5] He continued to play cricket around the world. In February 2013 it was announced that he would be captaining the Mumbai Indians team in the Indian Premier League.[6] and in March 2013 he was announced as the first international franchise player for the Caribbean Premier League.[7] Later that month it was revealed by Ponting that this would be his last season playing cricket, as at the end of the competition he would be retiring from all forms of the game.[8] In his final first class innings for Surrey against Notts he hit an unbeaten 169 bringing up a total of 82 first class 100s in an illustrious county career.
<p>
Candlestick Park hosted the Giants from 1960 to 1999 and the 49ers from 1971 until 2013.
The San </p>
<p>
testingThe San </p>
</div>

<div class="columns" id="content2"></div>
<div class="columns"id="content3"></div>
<div class="columns" id="content4"></div>
<div class="columns" id="content5"></div>
<div class="columns" id="content6"></div>
<div class="columns" id="content7"></div>
<div class="columns" id="content8"></div>
<div class="columns" id="content9"></div>
```